# Path of LANG variable in webos

Tags: linux, webos, palm

I want to know the path or the file location of LANG environment variable in webOS. i need to change the values for that variable.

Comment: Did you run the `env`  or `printenv` command, or simply `echo $LANG` or use `getenv(3)` function in C?

Comment: Actually I want to know the file, where the Regional settings details are stored.
In meego we can read the LANG in /home/meego/.config/i18n or  /etc/sysconfig/i18n.
In Webos, from where can i locate this?

Comment: You could use `grep -rn LANG= $HOME /etc` to find out where `LANG` is set.

Comment: actually i tried grep command in many ways.. but it is not showing any related files having the word lang